# Remove times in past from array of times

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdate

I have an array of times like this:

```
(
    "2000-01-01 23:48:00 +0000",
    "2000-01-01 02:15:00 +0000",
    "2000-01-01 04:39:00 +0000",
    "2000-01-01 17:23:00 +0000",
    "2000-01-01 13:02:00 +0000",
    "2000-01-01 21:25:00 +0000"
)
```

Which is generated from this code:

```
//loop through array and convert the string times to NSDates
                NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
                NSMutableArray *arrayOfDatesAsDates = [NSMutableArray array];
                for (NSObject* o in arrayTimes)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@",o);
                    NSDate *nsDateTime = [timeFormatter dateFromString:o];
                    [arrayOfDatesAsDates addObject:nsDateTime];
                }
                NSLog(@"times array: %@", arrayOfDatesAsDates);//
```

I am doing this because I am trying to get the time in the array which is next. My plan is to remove past times, order them, then take the first one as the next time.

How can I remove the past ones?

Thank you

Comment: given the dates are all in 2000, simplest method is to just empty out the array...

Comment: Who know!?  Nobody else but you knows what arrayTimes exactly contains.

Comment: @MarcB Well, that was just sample data, it changes every time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this will do...

```
NSArray *dateArray = ...

NSArray *filteredArray = [dateArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDate *date, NSDictionary *bind){
    NSComparisonResult result = [[NSDate date] compare:date];
    return result == NSOrderedAscending; 
}]];
```

filteredArray will then be all the dates from dateArray that are either now or in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If your representation in the question is correct, then your times are really strings with an ISO-like date format.

In theory this is bad - timestamps should be kept as `NSDate`s, as you are also implying yourself.

However (and if you are sure nobody is watching,) you can take advantage of the fact that the ISO date format allows for lexicographical sorting. The string     "2000-01-01 21:48:00 +0000" sorts before     "2000-01-01 23:48:00 +0000", so all you have to do is to filter with a string representing "now".

```
NSArray *times = @[
    // ... more times
    @"2000-01-01 13:02:00 +0000",
    @"2014-01-01 13:02:00 +0000",
    @"2015-01-01 13:02:00 +0000"
];

NSString *nowString = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithLocale: nil];

NSPredicate *stringPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF >= %@", nowString];

NSArray *filteredTimes = [times filteredArrayUsingPredicate: stringPred];
```

It *is* slightly hacky, so remember to comment it well. You might also want to make a few defensive tests to ensure that your timestamp format remains the same also in the future. Notice that if it slips to something like "2015-2-3 13:02:00 +0000" (without the leading zeroes in the month and day field) it will break, as "2015-10-15 13:02:00 +0000" will sort before that.

In reality, you should probably convert your timestamps to NSDate objects as soon as you read the data, in which case the predicate remains the same, and you just pass [NSDate date] directly instead of its string representation.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert these to NSDate objects and do sort the array with compare: